# htaccess rewrite parameter name to "nothing"

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I used the follow rule to rewrite `example.com/user-beavis` to `example.com/profil.php?user=beavis`

```
RewriteRule ^([^\-]*)user-(.*)$     $1profil.php?user=$2 [QSA]
```

But I want it to be `example.com/beavis` so I tried:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\-]*)(.*)$      $1profil.php?user=$2 [QSA]
```

but get 500 Internal Server Error

Is it even possible with any rule?

Comment: Check the error logs to know the actual error. Most likely it's an infinite loop though. Make a research on how `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f` might be helpful for you (I know it misses something important, I intentionally put it incomplete)

Comment: Why do you need QSA flag?

Comment: There is an endless loop in your second rule. That's why it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you explain me what you mean by infinite loop? I'm 100% noob with the htaccess stuff

Comment: @Matt123456 When it converts from beavis to profil.php, it tries to convert "profil.php" and does it infinitely. Because you didn't tell, where to stop.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert `example.com/beavis` to `example.com/profil.php?user=beavis`, use this:

```
RewriteRule ^(?!profil.php)(.*)$ /profil.php?user=$1 [L] [L]
```

I used a negative lookahead to protect from eternal loop.

Comment: I tried this but the whole site gets almost complete broken this way oO Mostly html/css errors

Comment: @Matt123456 This is because you have chosen a to use anything after slash as a user name. Maybe, we should use /user/beavis or something, that would allow us to distinct between the user name and non-user name?

Comment: Well I tried to make it example.com/user/beaver with: RewriteRule ^(?!profil.php)user/(.*)$ /profil.php?user=$1 [L] [L] but I get the same errors. It works fine with hyphen (user-beavis) but not with slash

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profil.php?user=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ profil.php?user=$1
```